# Reading from a file to compare characters

Tags: java

I need to compare test answers that I read from a file. The file looks like this:

1st line = Answer key

3rd Line and below = Student ID + Student answers to test

```
TTFTFTTTFTFTFFTTFTTF

ABC54102 T FTFTFTTTFTTFTTF TF
DEF56278 TTFTFTTTFTFTFFTTFTTF
ABC42366 TTFTFTTTFTFTFFTTF
ABC42586 TTTTFTTT TFTFFFTF
```

I put the answer key (1st line) in a String called ansKey with .nextLine(). I then print the student ID in a loop and put that student's answers in another String and pass both to a method:

```
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(file);

while(inFile.hasNextLine())
{
        //Student ID
        System.out.print("\t" + inFile.next());

        //Student Answers
        studentAnswers = inFile.nextLine();
        System.out.print("\t" + studentAnswers);

        //Get examGrade
        testGrade = examGrade(ansKey, studentAnswers.trim());

        //Display scores
        System.out.println(testGrade);
}
```

In my method I have a for loop to compare:

```
public static String examGrade(String ansKey, String studentAnswers)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < studentAnswers.length(); i++)
    {
        if(ansKey.charAt(i) == studentAnswers.charAt(i))
            score += 2;
        else if(studentAnswers.charAt(i) == ' ')
            score += 0;
        else
            score -= 1;
    }
}
```

All of this works perfectly fine. Except my professor doesn't want me to use trim(). If I take it out, I get ArrayIndexOutOfBounds. The reason I use trim() is because studentAnswers has a space in front when I read it with .nextLine(); I can't use .next() as some of the answers have spaces in between them.

I don't believe I can use anything I haven't used in my code already (Classes not seen here, arrays, etc..). I can use StringBuffer and StringTokenizer though. Not sure how those classes would help me however. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: just pass `studentAnswers.substring(1);` to `examGrade()`?

Comment: Interesting, never knew about that method. I'm guessing it starts at the second character when passed?

Comment: There are two flavors, in the form of `.substring(start)` and `.substring(start,stop)`. The first returns a string that starts from the specified index and goes to the end, the second stops before the specified end position. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I just asked my professor, and he doesn't want me to use substring either. Frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so if you can't use `trim()` or `substring()`, you'll have to go with arithmetic

```
public static String examGrade(String ansKey, String studentAnswers)
{
    //Now only go up to the answer key length
    for(int i = 0; i < ansKey.length(); i++)
    {
        //shift the index we are checking the student answers by 1
        int j = i + 1;
        if(ansKey.charAt(i) == studentAnswers.charAt(j))
            score += 2;
        else if(studentAnswers.charAt(j) == ' ')
            score += 0;
        else
            score -= 1;
    }
}
```